# Use Infinite Graph without installing the Product

Tags: graph-databases

I am currently writing a Infinite Graph Database Scanner where user can connect to remote InfiniteGraph by providing *.boot file. I am using Blueprint implementation of the InfiniteGraph

*i.e. **com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.ig.IGGraph***.

Now the code works perfectly when the machine already has installed version of InfiniteGraph, but fails in other cases. I tried to bundle the **bin**  folder from the installation directory with in my project, but it still fails.
The code I am using :

```
IGGraph graph = new IGGraph("D:\\PROPERTY_GRAPH_TEST.boot");

for (Vertex vertex : graph.getVertices()) {
    System.out.println("vertex.toString() = " + vertex.toString());
}
```

The exception I am gettings :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.objy.db.ObjyRuntimeException: Query setup error: Configuration Error: Unable to find the objectivity.crg file.
 at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.ig.IGGraph.<init>(IGGraph.java:67)
 at com.globalids.test.TestIGGraph.main(TestIGGraph.java:13)
Caused by: com.objy.db.ObjyRuntimeException: Query setup error: Configuration Error: Unable to find the objectivity.crg file.
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
 at com.objy.pm.ErrorManager.exceptionToThrow(Unknown Source)
 at com.objy.pm.ErrorManager.interpretKernelErrors(Unknown Source)
 at com.objy.pm.ErrorManager.checkRegisteredErrors(Unknown Source)
 at com.objy.pm.ExternalInterface.localErrorCheck(Unknown Source)
 at com.objy.pm.ExternalInterface.checkedLong(Unknown Source)
 at com.objy.pm.ExternalInterface.QueryScanItr(Unknown Source)
 at com.objy.pm.QueryScanItr.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.objy.db.internal.Query.execute(Unknown Source)
 at com.infinitegraph.impl.ConnectionManager.verifyCompatability(ConnectionManager.java:211)
 at com.infinitegraph.impl.ConnectionManager.connect(ConnectionManager.java:98)
 at com.infinitegraph.GraphFactory.openGraph(GraphFactory.java:227)
 at com.infinitegraph.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:86)
 at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.ig.IGGraph.<init>(IGGraph.java:62)
 ... 1 more
```

Can anyone help regarding this problem ??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your question. In fact the distribution requires more than just the "bin" copied over to run successfully.  Can you make sure that the "etc" and "plugins" directory are each copied into the same directory as your "bin" directory? This is due to the fact that InfiniteGraph uses the location of the "bin" directory to find the other configuration files in the "etc" and "plugins" directories (where the file, `objectivity.crg`, and other required files are located). You can email support@objectivity.com if you have any further questions. Thanks!